# NameError, name not defined - how to use a Variable before it it is defined/declared/assigned?

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, plotly-dash

I am currently building a dashboard which includes several graphs. The User has the option to use a plotly-dash dropdown menu to select the current month. The initial value of the graphs is always the current month.

Now to my issue. The graphs need several calculation, which are done beforehand in Pandas. The order of my code is as follows:

1. Define Dataframe
2. Make calculations in Pandas using month variable 'T' (which is hardcoded)
3. Generate Graphs using plotly and plot them in plotly dash with a dropdown menu
4. Run Server and print dashboard

My dropdown output, defined in step 3, is:

```
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected month "{}"'.format(value)
```

I'd like to use this output already just after step 1 - thereby I can make the calculations dynamic and make the chosen month not hardcoded. Essentially, I'd like to rewrite my hardcoded calculation lines as:

```
df[column].where[df['month_column'] = update_output].sum()
```

Any ideas on how I can use this variable update_output during the calculations without having a NameError (unidentified variable) error?

I have read about global, local, environment variables... though can't seem to find a way to use variables before being defined...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Where are you getting this NameError?  Please provide the full traceback.  Where is ```update_output``` defined?  Is it in the same file as the ```df[column].where[...]``` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to define a variable before you assignment. One way is by using the built in type functions. There are a lot of different type in pythons, you can visit this [site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) to know what all the types are, but you can give a variable an empty template of a type. All you have to do is use one of the built in type functions. For example, if you wanted to create an empty string type object you would do the following.

```
basic_string = str()
```

If you wanted to do just an empty object, this variable could be assigned any type (even custom objects), you would do the following.

```
basic_object = object
```